# Number of edges in a maximum independence edge set

Tags: graph-theory

I’m not realy sure. Are all these values true?

[image]

Comment: What aren’t you sure about? What have you done with this?

Comment: @LaarsHelenius I’m not sure about the value of alpha’ of Graph 2 and 3. I tried All the possibilities just with the definition of the Numbers in my head. But there is no solutions of the table in my tekstbook, and I really want to Check it.

Answer (score 2):

An independent edge set must have at most $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ edges, where $n$ is the number of vertices (since we "use up" two vertices per edge).  In these three examples, the bound is achieved:

In the first example, we have $6$ vertices, and $3$ independent edges depicted below:

[image]

In the second example, we have $11$ vertices, and $5$ independent edges depicted below:

[image]

In the third example, we have $10$ vertices, and $5$ independent edges depicted below:

[image]

Comment: Thnx! So all the Numbers in the table are correct? May I ask How I can sketch the graphs as beautifull as you did? Is there some program for it?

Comment: I use tikz, it's a LaTeX package.  I also use some patience (:.